# Как создать абстрактный класс с обобщенными параметрами, которые сами имеют обобщенные параметры?

Tags: c#, generics

Имеем 2 абстрактных класса

```
public abstract class Criteria<TEntity> where TEntity : class

public abstract class OperationResult<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

Хочется сделать что-то такое, но не выходит.

```
public abstract class Query<TCriteria<TEnitiy>, TOperationResult<TEntity>>
```

Comment: Не вполне понятно, что именно вы хотите. Возможно, вам нужен просто `public abstract class Query<TEntity> where TEntity : class`, чтобы внутри использовать `Criteria<TEnitiy>` и `OperationResult<TEntity>`?

Comment: Или `public abstract class Query<TEntity, TCriteria, TOperationResult> where TEntity : class where TCriteria : Criteria<TEntity> where TOperationResult : OperationResult<TEntity>`?

Comment: @VladD В класс запроса нужно передавать обобщенный критерий и получать обобщенный результат.

Comment: А почему тогда первый вариант не подходит?

Comment: @VladD А похоже на второй вариант, час проверю..

Comment: @VladD час в студию повтыкаю и вернусь...

Comment: Окей, давайте :)

Comment: @VladD второй вариант работает, спасибо. Оформите, пожалуйста, ответом, и я закрою вопрос.

Comment: Готово, написал!

Comment: А в `TCriteria` и `TOperationResult` будет использоваться один и тот же тип реализующий `TEntity`? Или могут быть разные?

Comment: @Андрей один и тот же класс у `TEntity`

Comment: @Bulson, ок, иначе бы пришлось добавлять четвертый параметр типа

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, вам нужно, чтобы параметры обобщения были сами по себе обобщениями `TEntity`. Такое требование прямо наложить нельзя, но можно схитрить, добавив третий параметр и условия:

```
public abstract class Query<TEntity, TCriteria, TOperationResult>
    where TEntity : class
    where TCriteria : Criteria<TEntity>
    where TOperationResult : OperationResult<TEntity>
{
    // ...
}
```